# Location tagging with the image clicked

Tags: android, android-studio

How should add I add the location(where the photo was clicked) with the photo clicked in Android Studio.I want to show the location of the place on the maps.

Comment: When you enable the geotag in Android, the OS adds a property in the EXIF header of the file. I know that in any regular programming language you can parse this header and retrieve the geolocation data (there are Apache tools for that). I'm not sure if there is any specific way to access this data via Android.

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: You can upvote the comment if ti helps you